# simpledb character limitation?

Tags: c#, amazon-simpledb

Does anyone know where to find documentation on character limitations on read/write to simpledb.  I've attempted some writes with special characters and it has failed.

Things like encoding and allowable character sets and charater settings would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1024 bytes and the limits are [here](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonSimpleDB/latest/DeveloperGuide/SDBLimits.html). Also note the section on "Attribute name, attribute value, and item name allowed characters".

Comment: the link did the trick! UTF-8 character limit (basically, whatever is allowed in a UTF-8 encoded xml doc)  Thanks!